# Why cant we call nonstatic method from static method?

Tags: java

I have a class Program. Here it has main method.It is static method. I created a simple 
**getAllSum** method to return sum of three values.But, if i remove static keyword then i get error as:

```
**Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method getALlsum(int, int, int) from the type Program
**
```

If I am calling a function from static method to non static method then,why it is necessary to become non static method to be static?

Static method I have learned about them is that:

1. Can be called from class name instead of using object.
2. Each object shares the same variable.

But,I am getting confuse why cant we call a nonstatic function from static function?What is the reason behind this?

```
public class Program {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int l=getALlsum(1,2,3);
        System.out.println(l);
    }

    public static int getAllSum(int a,int b,int c) {
        return (a+b+c);
    }

    }
```

Comment: `static` = one per class, not `static` = one per instance. If you are in a `static` method, then there is no instance of the class to invoke your methods on. `new Program(). getAllSum(1,2,3);`

Comment: Separately, just FWIW, *"Why cant we call nonstatic method from static method?"* You **can**, in situations where it's appropriate: You create an instance, then call the method on it.

Answer (score -1):

You cannot call non-static methods or access non-static fields from main or any other static method, because non-static members belong to a class instance, not to the entire class.

You need to make an instance of your class, and call your method